# How can I see if an UTxO holds an NFT in the postgres DB?

Tags: nft, cardano-db-sync, utxo, metadata

Is it possible to find out if an UTxO on the tx_out postgres table holds an NFT? OR in generell which kind of asset this UTxO holds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that an NFT is implemented as a multiasset (pretty sure that is not the only way) then this is relatively trivial:

```
select * from ma_tx_out where tx_out_id = <insert your tx_out id here> ;
```